# $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the only clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$; $[\boldsymbol{x,y}]$:={$(1-t)\boldsymbol{x}+t\boldsymbol{y}:t\in[0,1]$}

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am preparing for my exam and therefore practicing by solving some excercises. I need help for the following task:

> Prove that the only clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I know that you can find a lot of posts here where people tried to solve this task. But I want to do this with help of the hint our teacher gave us.

Hint: Assume, there is a nonempty proper subset S of $\mathbb{R^n}$, that is open and closed. Therefore, there exist $x\in S$ and $y\in S^c$. Where are the points on the connection route (hope this is the right english term) $[\boldsymbol{x,y}]$:={$(1-t)\boldsymbol{x}+t\boldsymbol{y}:t\in[0,1]$}?

I googled the term and found out that it has something to do with connected space/path connectedness. The problem is, that we never discussed this topic and thats why I don't know how to use the hint and where to start.

Is there anyone who can help me out? I would be grateful for any advice.

Edit: Here is my attempt:

Let's say: $t_0$=$\sup${$t\in[0,1]: (1-t)x+ty \in S$}. We are assuming that S is closed and open. Since S is closed, $t_0$$\neq 1$. If $t_0=1$ y would be in S but it isnt. So $0\leq t_0<1$. Also since S is closed, $((1-t_0)x+t_0y)$$\in$S. This means $((1-t)x+y)\in S^c$ for $t\in (t_0,1]$.This would mean that we would have infinite many t next to the limit $t_0$, with the consequence that $((1-t)x+ty)\in S^c$. This would mean, that $S^c$ is not closed. But we assumed that S is open too, there $S^c$ has to be closed too. A contradiction.

Comment: As already discussed in an answer's comments, the correct English terminology is "nonempty proper subset $S$" instead of "real nonempty subset $S$".

Comment: There's one other modification I'd make to your argument in addition to those suggested by FShrike. When you say "Since $\ S\ $  is closed  $\ t_0\ne1\ $" you're appealing to the fact that   $\ (1−t_0)x+t_0y\in S\ $ (unless I'm missing something), but your conclusion that  $\ (1−t_0)x+t_0y\in S\ $  from the closedness of  $\ S\ $  is not drawn until later. The argument would be cleaner if you were to draw this conclusion first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $\ t^*=\sup\big\{t\in[0,1]\,|\,(1-t)x+ty\in S\big\}\ $.  Is $ \big(1-t^*\big)x+t^*y\ $ in $\ S^c\ $? Is it in $\ S\ $?

Thanks to FShrike for pointing out that answering the original version of these questions wouldn't have been of any help.

Comment: This works fine unless $t^\ast=1$. I am not sure how you want them to conclude in that case. Perhaps you meant $\sup...\in S$? Then $t^\ast=1$ is impossible and you can make an open/closed contradiction

Comment: Yes, I had mistakenly taken $\ (1-t)x+ty\ $ as belonging to $\ S^c\ $ when $\ t=0\ $.

Comment: Nice, fixed now. +1, this hint is as good as it gets without telling them the answer directly

Comment: @FShrike My problem is 1st: I don't know where  this (1-t)x + ty even come from
2nd: If I understand it right we have to differentiate between  t* being 0, 1 or $\in (0,1)$ is that correct? And each case leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark No. Previously there was an issue with $t^\ast=1$ but they have corrected it since, so ignore those comments. Firstly answer their question: where is $(1-t^\ast)x+t^\ast y$? To answer that you can use some assumption you have made on $S$. However the fact that $y\notin S\implies t^\ast\neq1$ which leads to a contradiction with the *other* assumption you have made on $S$. I will write it up as a detailed answer if you wish but I strongly recommend you give this some thought based on their hint

Comment: @FShrike It was an answer to lonzas answer, I just tagged you becaus lonza as the post owner always will be notified and I thought, that maybe you could help me out.

Where is (1-t*)x+t*y? I don't know? Why? because I don't understand what t* is. I thought I should do it first for t*=0, then $t*\in(0,1)$ and t*=1, but you said no... Actually I don't even know why the hint of my teacher is proposing me to work with the term (1-t)x+ty...

Comment: The hint was: consider the line between $x$ and $y$. Hopefully you understand that $(1-t)x+ty,\,0\le t\le 1$ describes this line. $t^\ast$ is the least upper bound, intuitively the limit, of the $t$ that keep this line inside of $S$. It is your job to say whether this limit point is still inside $S$ (using one assumption on $S$), and then reach a contradiction using the other assumption on $S$

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I cannot say anymore really without giving you the answer directly. If you have thoughts about what I have said, you can ask (of course you can ask Ionza too, it is their post after all, I'm just responding because I have the free time)

Comment: @FShrike And I am thankful, that you are answering me. So my thoughts on this: You said that $y\notin S$ $\implies$ $t^*\neq1$. Why is that so. Because what if $(1-t)x+ty \in S$ for t=0,9999.... the supremum would be 1 right? Or did you use the assumption that S is closed. Then t* is the maxima and thus can't be 1. Do I understand that correct? So the supremum $t^* < 1$ $\in$ S. Therefore $\forall t\in (t^*,1]$ we get $(t-1)x+ty \in S^c$ which is a contradiction because we then have infinite many points $\in S^c$ next  to $(1-t^*)x+t^*y \in S$ which would mean that S^c is open. (next answer..)

Comment: @FShrike But we assumed S to be also open, so $S^c$ is closed. Thats a contradiction.

Comment: @Analysis_Mark To address this properly I'll need to post, not as an answer, but as a properly typed response to your attempt

Comment: @FShrike Well I can update my post with these thoughts and you then can respond to that.

Comment: I have added my "comment" (it was far too long) as a post. Your attempt has nice ideas but doesn't quite work, in particular the "infinitely many points close to"- argument is the right intuition but isn't phrased very precisely. I have covered the $t^\ast=1$ case (I ignored it before for reasons I won't go into (because they will give you the full answer pretty much), but I think it is good for me to cover this case specially)

Answer (score 0):

(You also have to assume that $S$ is neither empty, nor $\mathbf{R}^n$, and then find a contradiction.)

You won't need to use (path-)connectedness to prove this using the hint. Have you proven it for $\mathbf{R}^1$ already? Really all you have to do is use a similar argument, but not on a interval of $\mathbf{R}$ but on that line. The idea is to use supremum property of $\mathbf{R}$ and let $t_0 = \sup ...$

Comment: Well in my languaga "real subset" means that S is $\neq \mathbb{R^n}$. Probably the wrong english term. But yeah you are right, we have to assume that S is not empty too.

Comment: Haha, in my language too! In English we say proper instead of real, as it can be confused with anything that has to do with the real numbers ;). It was just a tiny remark, which is why it's put inside brackets

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, just a response to the comments which was too long to leave as a comment itself. This is to supplement Ionza's hint and to respond to the OP's attempt, based on this hint, in the comments below that post.*

For clarity, let's parametrise the line connecting $x$ and $y$ as $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^n,\,t\mapsto(1-t)x+ty$. We can rephrase $t^\ast$ from Ionza's post as $t^\ast=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}\{t:\gamma(t)\in S\}$

> If $t^\ast=1$, then this implies any interval $(t',1]$ will contain infinitely many $t$ such that $\gamma(t)\in S$. Notice however that $\gamma(t^\ast)=\gamma(1)=y\notin S$ as $y\in S^c$. Consider that $S$ closed implies $S^c$ is open. Thus, there is an open neighbourhood of $y$ which is completely contained in $S^c$.
>
> In your comment, you tried to say that "$S^c$  open" contradicts "$S^c$ closed". This is not generally true, and your argument for $S^c$ open doesn't quite work. I'll provide an example for the special $t^\ast=1$ case, you try and handle the cases $0\le t^\ast\lt1$ (the argument is similar).
>
> Anyway, consider this open ball about $y$. It will contain, by basic geometry of the ball, a connected line segment of $\gamma$, i.e. there is some $0\lt t'\lt 1$ such that $\{\gamma(t):t\in(t',1]\}\subseteq S^c$. However, as remarked at the start, there are infinitely many such $t$ for which $\gamma(t)\in S$, and $S\cap S^c=\emptyset$, contradicting the above claim. Therefore $S^c$ cannot be open at $y$, so it cannot be in general open, so $S$ cannot be closed. This is a contradiction.

For the cases $0\le t^\ast\lt1$, I will say only that "$S$ closed" implies something about where $\gamma(t^\ast)$ is (Ionza's original hint) and you want to obtain a similar contradiction involving openness.

Comment: Thank you for your massive answer, it made this more clear for me. In my post I edited that for the cases $0\leq t*<1$ $\gamma(t^*)$ $\in S$ because S is closed...$\gamma(t^*)$ is a boundary point of S. Wasn't that correct? Or is the argumentation incorrect?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct. Good job! You just need to not call $t_0$ a limit point, but rather $\gamma(t_0)$ is a limit point of $S^c$ but $\gamma(t_0)\in S$, which contradicts "$S^c$ closed" @Analysis_Mark

Comment: But we didn't assume $S^c$ to be closed. Or do you mean we say this means $S^c$ is not closed and thats why S is not open? Should I also do exactly the same by assuming that S is open instead of assuming that S is closed. Or isn't that necessary?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark $S$ is clopen if and only if $S^c$ is clopen. This is actually why we use clopenness as a criterion for connectivity. This is because $S$ open implies $S^c$ closed and $S$ closed implies $S^c$ open, using the complement properties of topology

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes, that is a cleaner way to conclude $t_0\neq1$. I made this post to address their attempted reasoning why $t_0\neq1$ since I thought their argument didn’t really make sense. This post also provides a stronger hint on how to continue for the other cases

Comment: My apologies.   I was intending  to address the OP, but pasted my comment into the wrong place.  I've now shifted it to where I had originally intended it to go.

Answer (score -2):

You just have to show that if $s$ is any proper non empty subset of $\mathbb R^n$ then  it cannot be open and closed simultaneously